# Initialize dictionary without values in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I would like to create dictionary with keys only. For example:

```
Dictionary <string, double> SmplDict= new Dictionary<string, double>();
SmplDict.Add("KeyOne");
SmplDict.Add("KeyTwo");
```

Of course, I can initialize with some predefined values, but this values will be overwritten, so I want only keys declared for now.
I tried

```
SmpDict.Add("KeyOne", null)
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put `null` value where `double` value is expected, as it is not a reference-type but a value-type:

```
Dictionary <string, double>
```

Instead, put `0`:

```
SmpDict.Add("KeyOne", 0)
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to keep put `null`s, mark your `double` value as nullable:

```
Dictionary <string, double?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to make it nullable, if you want to put `null`:

```
Dictionary <string, double?> SmplDict= new Dictionary<string, double?>();
```

Now you can add `null` as value:

```
SmpDict.Add("KeyOne", null)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dictionary<string, double?> smplDict = new();
smplDict.Add("KeyOne", default);
smplDict.Add("KeyTwo", default);
```

I would mention that it might be that you are doing something wrong that this is your need. Maybe you can use some other collection that is more suitable, e.g: [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 2):

If you want your values to be *null* then choose a type that can be nullable for the `Value`.Such as `double?`, `object` etc...

Answer (score 1):

While a double can't be null there is a Not-a-Number constant:

```
Dictionary <string, double?> SmplDict= new Dictionary<string, Double.NaN>();
```

for which you can check..